# some misunderstanding about `pandas.series.drop()`

Tags: python, pandas

I want to drop some specific rows in a `pandas.DataFrame`, while it seems that `pandas.Series.drop()`.What I have tried is as follows:

```
In[1]:
a_pd = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,2,3], [2,'?','x'],['s','d',4]]), columns=list('abc'))
a_pd
Out[1]:
    a   b   c
    0   1   2   3
    1   2   ?   x
    2   s   d   4

In[2]:
a_pd['b'].drop(a_pd['b'] == '?', inplace=True)
a_pd
out[2]:
    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
1   2   ?   x
2   s   d   4
```

Why it is the same `a_pd`???
Then I tried the `pandas.DataFrame.drop`, the result is more amazing:

```
In[3]:
b_pd = a_pd.drop(a_pd['b'] == '?')
out[3]:
a   b   c
1   2   ?   x
2   s   d   4
```

What happened? I cannot believe my eyes. Although I can easily choose the what I want by simply using `a_pd[a_pd['b'] != '?']`, I still want to try `drop()`.

Comment: By the way, can you share the tricks that copy contents from jupyter notebook? It seems that I cannot directly copy the output from jupyter opened in Chrome.

Comment: Drop works on indices, so you have to pass the index vector. `a_pd.drop(a_pd[a_pd['b'] == '?'].index)` - Please don't do this is real code though. It's ugly and hard to read. Use slicing notation `a_pd = a_pd.loc[a_pd.b != '?', :]` instead.

Comment: I tried `a_pd.drop(a_pd[a_pd['b'] == '?'].index)`, but an error occurred `IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pandas.drop() works on the labels associated with the row you want do delete, which in this case is 0, 1, or 2.  So you can delete the middle row by

```
a_pd.drop([1])
```

returns

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
2  s  d  4
```

Similarly, for the Series version of .drop(), will remove a row from the series.

```
a_pd['b'].drop([1])
```

returns

```
0  2
2  d
```

When you use the selection

```
a_pd['b'] == '?'
```

you get an array of boolean values

```
0    False
1    True
2    False
Name:  b, dtype: bool
```

and the result of

```
a_pd.drop(a_pd['b'] == '?')
```

is the same as

```
a_pd.drop([False, True, False])
```

But now is where things are not as expected, rather than apply a drop where the boolean value is True, this array is treated as an array of integer indices to drop namely

```
a_pd.drop([0, 1, 0])
```

And thus the result is a removal of the first two rows (the first row is removed twice)

```
   a  b  c
2  s  d  4
```

At least that is how it works on my version of pandas

```
pandas.__version__
$> u'0.17.1'
```